# Developing a live news feed information App / Android

Tags: android, xml, json, mobile, windows-mobile

I am in the planning stage of developing an cross platform mobile (Focused on Andriod market) App to display live news feeds from different websites.

I am thinking of using HTML5, and SQLite to save the information from feeds temporarily,

Now I am trying to figure out how to get the news off the news websites? I will need to use more than one source to get the data.

I am expecting some sort of tutorials, examples or guidance from you guys.

It will be a great help if anyone could guide me the correct direction ....

Comment: Use rss feed of the website. Parse the rss feed link and display it.

Comment: SO is not the right place for a question like this; please consult the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). But you may want to get familiar with RSS.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.. Yes, RSS feeds will be the option I feel.. I may have to dig deep into see how I can go about it.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested RSS is the best solution. For example you can find RSS feed for BBC news site here: http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/video_and_audio/world/rss.xml

This is a good android RSS tutorial: http://www.ingeniumblog.net/2012/01/making-a-slick-rss-reader-in-android/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, will check that further and get more information..

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned before me, RSS is probably the best solution. When loading the data, it doesn't take all that long (But it depends on how many items).

There are plenty of ways to fetch the feed and store it somewhere, but if you need to article body then Jsoup is probably the easiest of ways.

This is what I based one of my apps off of:

http://techiedreams.com/android-simple-rss-reader/

The article itself isn't really that descriptive, so you will probably have to dig around the source code (There is really only one class that you would need to look at)

Comment: that's a cool example.. I will certainly use it. Jsoup I haven't heard of it, as I understand Jsoup helps you to extract information from the HTML content, how is it different from fetching RSS feeds.. Sorry if I am asking silly question.. Thank you

Comment: You are correct about Jsoup, but if you fetch and parse the feed, you can modify the body of the fetched feed items and then put them into what ever it is that you want to store your RSS feed.

Jsoup can extract as well as modify HTML, in the example that I linked, you can see how it is used in the DOMParser class

Comment: Sorry for the late comment, I am still learning a lot of stuff about parsing feeds and I will certainly keep Jsoup as an option. Thank you.